# Gradle Ktlint plugin fails on Java 16

Tags: java, gradle, java-platform-module-system, ktlint, java-16

After upgrading to Java 16 I am not able to make ktlint gradle plugin to work. It's throwing

```
Execution failed for task ':runKtlintCheckOverMainSourceSet'.
A failure occurred while executing org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint.worker.KtLintWorkAction
   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)

Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task     ':runKtlintCheckOverMainSourceSet'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$3(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:268)

Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint.worker.KtLintWorkAction
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:142)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:94)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.pom.java.LanguageLevel.<clinit>(LanguageLevel.java:25)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.<init>(CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.java:26)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.java:42)
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @58f87189
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:252)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:269)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.DynamicBundle.<clinit>(DynamicBundle.java:22)
        ... 32 more
```

I am aware that it's caused by stricter module checks (JEP 396) but I am not able to set the JVM args for the plugin. I tried:

- Setting env variable `JAVA_OPTS=--illegal-access=warn`
- Setting `org.gradle.jvmargs=--illegal-access=warn -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options=--illegal-access=warn` in `gradle.properties`

But neither of the attempts helped, I am out of ideas.

Comment: Issue https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle/issues/461

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Java 16 is not supported by Gradle 6.x and will be supported by Gradle 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the Gradle plugin to get the latest version according to the [migration guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html):

```sh
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 7.0
```

That should fix this error message. Otherwise, you can also change the version in the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-bin.zip
```

I also updated the kotlin plugins like `kotlin("jvm")` to the latest version `1.4.32`.